# Mask a shape inside a container Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I need mask an ellipse inside a container but it is on the right at the end of the container with ClipRect I can't move the shape.
Someone can help me, the final idea is this:

[My final idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B18Es.png)

UPDATE:
Now i got a similar result by doing this:

```
Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 300,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        child: ClipRRect(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 250, bottom: 12,),
            child: OverflowBox(
              maxHeight: 100,
              maxWidth: 200,
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfJ7G.png)

But now the border radius disappear.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: You need to post some code

Comment: I have updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Hello i would do something like

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 350,
          height: 80,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (_, constrains) {
                return Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: constrains.maxWidth,
                      height: constrains.maxHeight,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      right: -50,
                      top: -60,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 140,
                        height: 140,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Text('Your Content Here'),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Ofcourse you have to play with the sizes and that kind of things